# What is the structure of the data and labels in tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist input_data

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to learn to introduce data to conv nets properly in Tensorflow, and a majority of example code uses `from import tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data`.

It's simple when you can use this to access mnist data, but not helpful when trying to establish the equivalent way to structure and introduce non-mnist data to similar models.

What is the structure of the data being imported through the mnist examples, so that I can use example cnn walkthrough code and manipulate my data to mirror the structure of the mnist data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format of the MNIST data obtained from that example code depends on exactly how you initialize the [`DataSet`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/901ab86f35bc24461bad6d3145e62874d105038f/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/mnist.py#L104) class. Calling [`DataSet.next_batch(batch_size)`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/901ab86f35bc24461bad6d3145e62874d105038f/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/mnist.py#L161) returns two NumPy arrays, representing `batch_size` images and labels respectively. They have the following formats.

- If the `DataSet` was initialized with `reshape=True` (the default), the images array is a `batch_size` by `784` matrix, in which each row contains the pixels of one MNIST image. The default type is `tf.float32`, and the values are pixel intensities between `0.0` and `1.0`.
- If the `DataSet` was initialized with `reshape=False`, the images array is `batch_size` by `28` by `28` by `1` 4-dimensional tensor. The `28` corresponds to the height and width of each image in pixels; the `1` corresponds to the number of channels in the images, which are grayscale and so have only a single channel.
- If the `DataSet` was initialized with `one_hot=False` (the default), the labels array is a vector of length `batch_size`, in which each value is the label (an integer from `0` to `9`) representing the digit in the respective image.
- If the `DataSet` was initialized with `one_hot=True`, the labels array is a `batch_size` by `10` matrix, in which each row is all zeros, except for a `1` in the column that corresponds to the label of the respective image.

Note that if you are interested in convolutional networks, initializing the `DataSet` with `reshape=False` is probably what you want, since that will retain spatial information about the images that will be used by the convolutional operators.

Comment: As a quick follow-up, is there a way to initialise other data as a dataset type, in order to use .next_batch() apart from on the mnist data?

Comment: The MNIST example code isn't really reusable for other types of dataset, because it contains various details of the specific data format. You might try taking a look at the other example dataset libraries in `tf.contrib.learn` here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets